# Can we create recursive functions only by using if-else statements?

Tags: recursion, semantics

I have to show whether a program containing only *if-else* statements but no loops is able to calculate the following type of functions: $f^n(x)$. The function $f$ is applied $n$ times to $x$, so I guess this is a recursive function.

How can I prove that formally?

Comment: It's not necessarily recursive. You could use, e.g., a for loop to solve it iteratively. Thinking about iteration might suggest an answer to your problem.

Comment: Do you mean that if/else is the only type of flow-control statement? Because you'll probably need some method invocations, at least.

Comment: My question is: Can I create a recursive function by only using if-else statements? No loops. Only if-then-else stuff.

Comment: If $n$ is fixed and $f$ itself is not recursive and does not use a while loop, the target function does *not* require recursion. Please edit the question to focus and either that or what you ask in your comment.

Answer (score 5):

If a program doesn't include any loop, recursion or equivalent construct, then it cannot express recursive computations.

In order to write a formal proof, you'd need to define your language formally. “Equivalent construct” can include some exotic things such as parallel execution, exception handlers, higher-order functions (leading to [fixpoint combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixpoint_combinator)), meta-execution facilities ([`eval`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)), etc. that let recursion in through a backdoor.

Suppose that a language contains only the following constructs: constants, assignments, sequence (do a then do b), functions operating on base types (but not functions taking functions as arguments), conditionals (`if (x == y)`), some primitives on base types (e.g. `+`, `*`). Then the execution of the program takes a time that is at most exponential, and in particular bounded, in the size of the program (the unit of time is an elementary expression, e.g. `x := y` takes one unit, `x := y + z` takes two units). In a nutshell, function application at most multiplies the complexity of the function by the complexity of the program, and the rest is linear.

Since this language can only express bounded-time computations, it cannot express all recursive programs (and in fact it cannot even express all primitive recursive programs).

Comment: I have seen examples of very reasonable limited recursion, where the natural solution used recursion, but only one level deep.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the cleanest way to have a recursive calculation function is to ONLY use a if-else. Since there are usually only two main conditions in a recursive function( 1 - base case met, 2 - base case not met) it is only logical to only have two condition checks. The **if** checks for the base case, if the base case has not been reached **else** does calculations and sends the new recursive call. Below is some pseudo code for a recursive function for the example you provided.

```
int recursiveFunction(int n,int x)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
       return x;
    }
    else
    { 
       x=x*x//or whatever work is being done
       return (n-1,x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure entirely what you mean. Are you allowed method invocations? If so you can provide this example:

```
def apply_multiple(f, x, n):
  if n == 0:
    return x
  else:
    return f(apply_multiple(f, x, n-1))
```

If you're talking about writing that particular function without ANY flow control other than if statements, you can't. Consider the line number you're currently on. This can only increase, so for a finite program there are only a finite number of states it can be in. This isn't going to work if n can be an arbitrary number.

Answer (score -2):

In Elixir, this would be as easy as

```
def nthApply(f, x, n) do
  if n < 1 do
    x
  else
    nthApply(f, f.(x), n-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't your answer covered by [robbie_c's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12774/83244)?

Comment: Maybe. I'm just anal about doing every recursion tail recursively.